# Javascript Class variable reassign

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am creating a `Class` instance, I am kinda stuck on variable reassign, like below

```
class A {
  constructor() {
    this.checkBoolen = false
  }

  checkBoolen = false // error, asks to install @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties to get support.

  click() {
   document.addEventListener('click', e => {
      this.checkBoolen=true // <- a class constructor's prototype property can't be reassigned.
   })
  }

  doSomthing() {
   if(this.checkBoolen = true // <- never get there) {
    console.log('do something')
       setTimeout(function(){ this.checkBoolen = false}, 3000)
   }
  }
}
```

Looks like either I need to use `@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties`? or change the `Class` to a function? I am wondering if there is a way to change variable inside `Class` or it is a bad practice?

Comment: Multiple Syntax Errors

Comment: If you use arrow functions instead of traditional function then it may solve your issue. This is due to scope of variable will be maintained.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple mismatch brackets, class keyword is uppercased

```
class A {
  constructor() {
    this.checkBoolen = false
  }

   checkBoolen = false // error, asks to install @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties to get support.

  click() {
   document.addEventListener('click', e => {
      this.checkBoolen=true // <- a class constructor's prototype property can't be reassigned.
   });
  }

  doSomthing() {
   if(this.checkBoolen = true )// <- never get there) {
    console.log('do something')
   }
}
```

And you can use it like this

```
let obj = new A();
obj.checkBoolen=true
obj.doSomthing()
```

Answer (score 1):

I would not make my structure like this, but perhaps you should take a look.

```js
class WTF{
  constructor(clickElement){
    this.clickElement = clickElement; this.checkBool = false;
    clickElement.onclick = e => {
      this.click();
      console.log(this.checkBool);
    }
  }
  click(){
    this.checkBool = !this.checkBool;
    return this;
  }
}
let wtf = new WTF(document);
```

Just keep clicking on the page.

Answer (score 0):

you have typeo 
1- start class with lowercase class
2- check eventlistener syntax

```
    class D {
  constructor() {
    this.checkBoolen = false;
  }

  checkBoolen = false // error, asks to install @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties to get support.

  click() {
   document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      this.checkBoolen=true; // <- a class constructor's prototype property can't be reassigned.
   });
  }

  doSomthing() {
   if(this.checkBoolen = true ) {
    console.log('do something');
   }
  }
}
```